# Best performance - mirroring against duplicate operations on 2 databases

Tags: mysql

Consider having 2 mysql databases, each for an application. Main database with the main office application, second database for an aux application. In order to get better speed for the main database, which will you took and why?

1. Complete Mirroring
2. BEFORE OPERATION trigger a duplicate of the operation in the second database

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

Redundant data is a no-no in a database.

To access tbl1 in db1 and tbl2 in db2 in the same query, use the db.tbl syntax:

```
SELECT a.x, b.y
    FROM db1.tbl1 AS a
    JOIN db2.tbl2 AS b ON ...
    WHERE ...
```

Comment: Yeah. But we cannot slow down the main database, so the idea was to replicate data needed in another database. If your advice is not having redundant data, how will you do that?

Comment: "slow down the main database" -- That is a strange concept.  Please describe the symptoms that lead you to the belief.  There may be solutions involving better indexes, changes in locking, replication, etc.  Keep in mind that a `TRIGGER` costs something, too.

Comment: The main database is one out of my control. It is used by another application and we cant change the tables in any case. This application runs slowly (maybe a poor optimization o db design, it could be). We have to do another application using the data from the "main database" without overloading it, so I am searching for the best solution at all.

Comment: I did not suggest changing the tables -- just get rid of the trigger and change the `SELECT`.

Comment: Rick, as I said, I cannot change the tables because they belongs to another application. Think at them as main database was a concrete block, cant touch it. So what I need is to read this concrete block without slowing the another application.